# React passing two functions as a call backs to this.setState

Tags: reactjs

I want to have multiple callbacks after running this.setState()

This code works and `this work is printed`.

```
savePitch(e){
        this.setState({savedPitches: [...this.state.savedPitches, this.state.addNewPitch]})
        this.setState({addNewPitch: {
            id: this.state.addNewPitch.id + 1,
            pitchName: '',
            shortCut: '',
            subject: '',
            pitch: ''
        }},
        () => {console.log('this worked')},
        )
        this.toggleNewPitchForm()
    }
```

However if I want to have **two** functions run, I tried below but it doesn't work as expected.

```
savePitch(e){
        this.setState({savedPitches: [...this.state.savedPitches, this.state.addNewPitch]})
        this.setState({addNewPitch: {
            id: this.state.addNewPitch.id + 1,
            pitchName: '',
            shortCut: '',
            subject: '',
            pitch: ''
        }},
        () => {console.log('this worked')},
        () => {console.log('then this worked')},
        )
        this.toggleNewPitchForm()
    }
```

What changes should I make to make this run as expected?

Comment: `setState` take only one callback function, not two.

Comment: i'm curious to know what is the reason behind this, why would you need a second callback? by the way you know that react batches the `setState`  calls...

Comment: is there a way to include both functions in one callback?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing multiple functions as callback in setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788156/passing-multiple-functions-as-callback-in-setstate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply call the methods sequentially within an arrow function:

```
this.setState(..., () => {
    (() => { console.log('one') })()
    (() => { console.log('two') })()
}
```

Comment: I got this error: `App.js:174 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function`

Comment: (but this is what I was looking for)

Comment: this answer helped me! :)

Comment: I also got the same error `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function` but I was just missing the second set of parentheses for the iife.

Answer (score 3):

Just define the method that will call the other methods.

```
const myMethod = () => {
  myMethod1();
  myMethod2();
  myMethod3();
};

this.setState({addNewPitch: {...}}, myMethod);
```